# Issues with YUI Compressor for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, yui, yui-compressor

I am using the YUI Compressor library for .NET found on http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/
and I am having trouble minifying jQuery plugin files since it's crashing with syntax errors which I believe YUI thinks are present in the code. Is there a workaround or an option that I may be missing when dealing with this types of files? My options are currently the following;

Encoding = UTF-8

Nothing else was set up, so I am assuming that there are default parameters for the rest of the options.

Thanks

Comment: I've never had a problem compressing jQuery (or any jQuery plugins for that matter) with YUI, can you specify which plugin(s) you're referring to?

Comment: The filename is jquery.chromatable-1.4.2.js The issue YUI is throwing is "missing formal paramter"

Comment: .net 4.5 includes css/js/and other minifiers/compressors/consolidators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's going on. Apparently this plugin is using an identifier that is considered a reserved word by EcmaScript. I haven't found which word is breaking everything up. But at least I now have a starting point. Thanks to everyone for your time.

Comment: If you find out which word it is that is causing this, it would be useful to make an update to this post and mark it as an answer. That way it might be more helpful to others encountering similar problems in the future.

Comment: Mi problem  is whit "let". there are any solution, in .net yuicompressor?